# Redirect Debugging

Tags: javascript

There's an error in the code, but I can't figure out what.

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at doRedirects (VM8 worker.js:6)
    at event (VM8 worker.js:2)
Uncaught (in response) ReferenceError: req is not defined

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(doRedirects(event.request))
})

const newLocationHost = "developers.cloudflare.com";

async function doRedirects(request) {
    let reqUA = req.headers.get('user-agent')
    if (reqUA.matches('curl').true) {
        let newLocation = "https://"+newLocationHost
        return Response.redirect(newLocation, 302)
    }
    return fetch(request);
}
```

Comment: You should make it easier to answer your question by pointing out what *exactly*  is going wrong, at what point, and describe what you tried to find or fix the error.

Comment: Edit your question and include: what did you expect to happen and what did happen.

Comment: This is the error prompt: Uncaught (in response) ReferenceError: req is not defined. For the line aforementioned by @kowsky

Comment: Did you mean to write `request.headers.get('user-agent')`?

Comment: Not entirely sure. The script was given deliberately broken, so I wouldn't think it would be really broken.

Answer (score 0):

`req.headers.get` will return a string or null ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get)).

Strings have a `match` method that accepts a regular expression ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

Try changing this line:

```
 if (reqUA.matches('curl').true) {
```

To this:

```
if (requUA !== null && reqUA.match(/curl/)) {
```

Another issue is the `Response` class does not have a `redirect` method ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)).

Try changing this line:

```
return Response.redirect(newLocation, 302)
```

To this:

```
return new Response(undefined, {
  status: 302,
  statusText: 'Found',
  headers: {
    Location: newLocation
  }
});
```

Comment: I think there's a token error.

  
This script:

    return new Response(undefined, {
      status: 302,
      statusText: 'Found',
      headers: {
        Location: newLocation
      }
    );

It doesn't end properly I think. Sorry, my JS knowledge is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and OP probably fixed this already but in the interest of providing an answer...

The issue lies with this section:

```
async function doRedirects(request) {
    let reqUA = req.headers.get('user-agent')
```

Here, you're using `req.headers` when the request variable is `request`. You should therefore be using `request.headers`.